# repair_packages: command not found

Tags: terminal, error, macos

I've been having problems with WebRoot internet security ever since upgrading to Sierra.  I was told to run the following command from Terminal

```
sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --verify --standard-pkgs /
```

When I did so, I got the following message

```
sudo: /usr/libexec/repair_packages: command not found
```

WebRoot said they couldn't help me.  They said I should contact Apple ... which I did.  Still no help.

Any suggestions as to why I'm getting this message and how to fix it?  I've already reinstalled Sierra once ... which should have fixed the problem, but didn't.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/354432/the-command-line-would-not-let-me-repair-my-disk-permission-on-mac-mojave/354434#354434

Answer (score 1):

You're getting that message because the `repair_packages` command no longer exists in Sierra. Repairing permissions, which is what they're trying to get your system to do, is automatically handled during software updates now. I'm not sure what the underlying issue they're trying to fix is, but repairing permissions on system files probably is not the issue anyway, especially on a clean install.

Apple's not going to be able to help you because Sierra doesn't have that utility. You'll need to go back to WebRoot and ask them how to resolve your issue *on Sierra*.

(For a company that claims to be selling internet security software, you'd think they'd be a little more versed in the OS for that software, especially before asking a user to run a command in Terminal!)

Comment: For an unrelated issue faced by many users on a helpline I help to run for an online gaming system; we actually just tell people to uninstall Webroot & get a proper antivirus instead :/